# PCM5102A purple dac not working

Tags: audio, pi-zero-w, modules, i2s, pi-zero-w-2

This never worked for me :( I tied with two purple color PCM5102A DACs from aliexpress and eBay ! None worked when connecting to my raspberry pi zero 2W as described !

I have used the steps as detailed in https://blog.himbeer.me/2018/12/27/how-to-connect-a-pcm5102-i2s-dac-to-your-raspberry-pi/ but it never worked for me !

It gives a red light saying power is connected! The moment the board is connect to an active computer speaker it starts making buzzing noise ! If I try to play any audio I only get noise ! Is there some soldering or bridging needs to be done on the board ? Please let me know if there are any special settings that needs to be enabled on this board

I tried the below :

1. Connect XSMT pin on dac board to 5v on Pi Zero 2W and Connect FMT pin on dac board to Gnd on Pi zero 2W
2. Connect XSMT pin on dac board to A3V3 pin on the dac board and Connect FMT pin on dac board to AGND  on the dac board
3. Connect SCLK on dac board to raspberry Pi Zero 2W Gnd

I have the same result - Buzzing sound when connecting dac to an active speaker and when I start audio file I still get the same buzzing sound !

Looking for some suggestions and recommendations to understand what I might I have missed.

This is the board I used from Aliexpress and eBay -

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204367400720

The solder pads on back of the baord look exactly like the  pictures on ebay link above 4 sets of jumpers and each jumper having 3 pads ! I see some soldering for high / low but I highly suspect some thing needs to be changed on these jumpers !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the problem is already resolved but maybe you got the similar problem [as I have](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147159/had-to-bridge-the-pcm5102a-in-order-to-get-audio-output-with-volumio)