# Had to bridge the PCM5102A in order to get audio output with volumio

Tags: gpio, pi-4, audio-playback

I’m working on a project with volumio so I decided to use this DAC for better Output. However I stumbled across a problem.

I mostly followed this guide: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/how-to-make-pcm5102-dac-work-on-raspberry-pi-zerow](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/how-to-make-pcm5102-dac-work-on-raspberry-pi-zerow://)

I also bridged the pads for the SCK, so I didn’t have to connect it to ground.

But after connecting it to the Raspberry and using the HiFiBerry DAC option in Volumio I still got no audio.

After a little of tinkering I found out that bridging two of the pads corresponding to soft mute control (XSMT), will get audio output. Before there was just some noise.

Now I wonder if this is normal and it just wasn’t mentioned in the guide or if I got a defective unit.

Down below are pictures of the wiring and soldering. Maybe I made a mistake there…

[image]

[image: strong text]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but I found on this forum another member mentioning about this.

> On the back (non-component side) there are 4 sets of 3 pads for the 4 functions:
> FLT - Filter select : Normal latency (Low) / Low latency (High)
> DEMP - De-emphasis control for 44.1kHz sampling rate: Off (Low) / On (High)
> XSMT - Soft mute control(1): Soft mute (Low) / soft un-mute (High)
> FMT - Audio format selection : I2S (Low) / Left justified (High)
> The centre pad is connected to the corresponding pin. Each of these function pads may be bridged with solder either high or low (or the pins connected to +3.3V / 0V). (My board is supplied with 1, 2 & 4 bridged low and 3 bridged high, i.e. normal latency filter, 44.1kHz de-emphasis disabled, soft-mute not asserted, I2S audio format.)

Comment: Yeah I’ve already seen this post but I didn’t think it should be necessary to bridge.
I’ve also seen this video: https://youtu.be/1T9PKLeBDFc?si=HAj7SpHyOER-Fztp


He hasn’t bridged those pads it seems like, so I wondered why I didn’t get any audio like this…

Comment: Yes is strange how some are getting output without the bridge. I have another ugly error now "Error

Failed to open "alsa" (alsa); Failed to open ALSA device "volumio": Device or resource busy".   Sometimes will output but most of the times I'm getting this error.